# docker-compose passing environment variables into container possible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, arguments, devops

docker does really confuse me....
I am trying to use the "environments" variable as well as the .env file to pass variables into the container that will be created. Sadly without success.

What my setup is:

docker-compose.yml

```
# dockerfile version 3.8 -> 18.07.2020
version: "3.8"

# services basicly means scalable amount of containers
services:

    testalpine:
        image: testenvalpine
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: test-dockerfile
            args:
                - DB_NAME=nextcloud
                - DB_USER=nextcloud
        # todo only use https and self sign certificate
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        environment:
            - env1=hello
            - env2=world
        networks:
            - nextcloudnetwork
        # todo include redis and mariadb 
networks:
    nextcloudnetwork:
        # std driver seems to be overlay?
        driver: overlay
```

Dockerfile:
test-dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
LABEL maintainer="xddq <donthavemyownemailyet:(((>"

ARG DB_NAME=default
ARG DB_USER=default

ENV env1=dockerfile env2=$DB_NAME

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", \
    "echo DB_NAME: $DB_NAME DB_USER: $DB_USER env1: $env1 env2: $env2" ]
```

My .env file

```
DB_NAME=nextcloud
DB_USER=nextcloud
```

The output I did EXPECT:

```
DB_NAME:nextcloud DB_USER: nextcloud env1: hello env2:nextcloud
```

The output I got:

```
DB_NAME: DB_USER: env1: dockerfile env2: nextcloud
```

Does this mean ".env" and ENV variable in docker-compose are completely useless for the env variables inside the container that will be created? I mean I could only get any result using the ARG variable..? :/

greetings

Comment: I think your confusion is around `ARG` and assuming that it populates environment at runtime. `ARG` only populates environment variables at build time and is used to pass variables to container steps while building the image. The `.env` file is only going to override `ENV` in the container or the `environment` map in the compose file.

Comment: Mhh it is less about ARG and more about ENV. When I pass values in a .env file I still have to pass the key:ARG value:ENV to the dockerfile to access the env variables  later in my container. Which was pretty confusing. I thought ENV variables when set in the docker-compose can be used inside my finished container no matter what I am doing. But ENV variables inside docker-compose only seem to be usable inside docker-compose.

Comment: They can. But in your example you expected output that depends on `DB_NAME` and `DB_USER` which are build time `ARG` and will always be blank at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .env is not automatically passed to the container, you need to declare it in your docker-compose.yml using `env_file:` [Explanation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/). The environment inside the dockerfile should be overriden by the ones in your docker-compose file not sure why this is not the case.

Comment: Oh wow. They are really making a difference between .env and env_file ? :D
I will check that out later and will give you the top answer if that works. I did a workaround assigning ARGS to the build and passing them the values of my .env variables inside the docker-compose. Which felt insanely stupid.